# Whats wrong with s.Count(Char.IsLetter)

Tags: compiler-errors, f#

F#

```
let s = "bugs 42 bunny"
s.Count(fun c -> Char.IsLetter(c))
s.Where(fun c -> Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray()
s.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray()
s.Count(Char.IsLetter) // error
```

Why does **only the last line** fail to compile:

> Error FS0002: This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected

Comment: This is a type inference edge case ([explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12937079/162396)).

Comment: daniel, i guess you hit the point. the difference between Where() and Count() is that Count() has an overload without argument and the compiler obviously matches this argument less overload and gets stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's an edge case of type inference wrt member overloading. The difference between `Count` and `Where` is that the former has two overloads with different number of arguments.

You can work around by specifying conversion from F# function to `System.Func<_, _>`:

```
s.Count(Func<_, _>(Char.IsLetter))
```

Of course, it's even uglier than the corresponding version:

```
s.Count(fun c -> Char.IsLetter(c))
```

You could file a bug at https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic so that it may be fixed in the F# vNext.

Note that in F#, you don't often use Linq functions. You can either do:

```
s |> Seq.sumBy (fun c -> if Char.IsLetter c then 1 else 0)
```

or

```
s |> Seq.filter Char.IsLetter |> Seq.length
```

Answer (score 3):

Daniel appears to be correct about the [type inference problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12937079/162396).

It doesn't look as nice, but the following appears to work.

```
Char.IsLetter |> s.Count
```

Comment: Good call. Using the left to right evaluation in your favor instead of fighting it.